# serenity junit - after run not display index.html

Tags: serenity-bdd

after i run test has error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo_web_serenit_junit: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

i trying java 11 version but not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sis0D.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pevAP.png)